# Get variable value from method to outside

Tags: android, variables

```
 private String u_id;
 private String u_name;

@Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                if(Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null) {
                    mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile, Profile profile2) {
                            // profile2 is the new profile
                            u_id = profile2.getId().toString();
                            u_name = profile2.getName().toString();
                            mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
                        }
                    };
                    // no need to call startTracking() on mProfileTracker
                    // because it is called by its constructor, internally.
                }
                else {
                    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                    u_id = profile.getId().toString();
                    u_name = profile.getName().toString();
                }
                /*new CreateNewProduct().execute();*/
                /*updateFacebookButtonUI();*/
            }
```

I want get value u_id and u_name to add arraylist, but it return null. I tried log have result. I need way resolve. Thanks :(

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("u_id", u_id)); // return null
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("u_name", u_name)); // return null
```

Comment: set `public String u_id=" ";` and check `profile.getId().toString()` is `null` or not

Comment: where is  code for storing value in that variable

Comment: You should learn how to work with multithreading ... the data is ready in onSuccess, end of story, not right after you queue the request ... blocking UI thread is bad m'kay?

Comment: Oh, variable in same class, I declare it before onCreate

Answer (score 0):

Variables `u_id` and `u_name` can be `null` only if they were not initialised. You don't set their value when adding the field to the class.

```
private String u_id; //only type and name set, not the value
```

I think if you're sure their value have to be set somewhere in the inner methods (doesn't matter in `if` or `else` either), it's not so dangerous to leave it like this. Also I would bet you're calling `params.add(...)...` *after* the above lines, unless it would cause the variables being `null` too...

But if you really want to get something back from your variables, you can initialise them as plain empty strings (`""`),

```
private String u_id = ""; //the variable's value is set too
```

and maybe later handle the "empty-string" checking before adding their value to your `List<NameValuePair>` variable; however it's not necessary. The main thing is: this way you can be 100% sure your variables won't be `null`...

---

**EDIT #1**: I don't know much about the structure of your file which contains `onSuccess()` method and the class with your list inside of it, but I would say it's another Java class file (`MyClass.java` or similar). I'm not an expert in Android multithreading, but I would say there is not anything that could block your inner class with your list to access the fields in the outer base class. You can reach fields anytime and anywhere in a class, no matter you want to do it in that very class or in the 10th nested inner class or method.

So unless your code does not look similar to this, I would think my first answer (above the edit) should be the solution. Maybe you should provide the code of your full class(es) to find the best solution, not just parts like you did first time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, adding "" results will not be null, but I want to get the value of the variable inside the `onSuccess` method to pass to the List below. The list below is in another class in same file with on Success